# Problems creating a static route (or any route)

Tags: routing, virtual-machines, internet, interface

I have been using this website to read about routing tables and static routes, but I can't seem to get my own static route going.

Here is the situation:

-> PC:
1x Wifi NIC 192.168.1.19 with mask 255.255.255.0 and gateway 192.168.1.1
1x LAN NIC 172.16.0.1 with mask 255.255.0.0

-> ESXi Server
LAN NIC 172.16.0.3 with mask 255.255.0.0 (Management Network)

-> Windows Server 2012 VM (runs on ESXi Server)
LAN NIC 172.16.0.4 with mask 255.255.0.0 and gateway 172.16.0.1 (???)

The nodes in the 172.16.0.0 network can ping one another.

Now I want the VM to be able to connect to the internet, so I figured I had to make a route on my PC, since it has 2 interfaces.

I did *route add 172.16.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 192.16.1.19* but that did not work.
What am I not doing correctly?
Or can I not use a static route here?

Comment: If you are using Virtualbox as your VM manager, it will have already set up routes to your internet interface.

Comment: What does the ESXi guest have to do with your computer? Why would you set your computer as the DG for the ESXi guest?

Answer (score 1):

You **do not need** to configure routing (in the sense of specifying routes) on the PC.

You **need** to:

1. enable routing on the PC (i.e. to enable packet flow between interfaces)
2. set up NAT mapping on the PC (for the 172.16.0 network, or only the VM)

Since you did not provide even the OS type of the PC, you have to find the specific instructions yourself.